# List's to csv Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Помогите пожалуйста, испытываю большие проблемы с записью CSV, если все нижеописанное вывести как print, то всё супер, а в CSV записать не получается:

```
 File "C:/Users/VIK/PycharmProjects/untitled2/tests.py", line 71, in <module>
    write_csv(get_all_items(html))
  File "C:/Users/VIK/PycharmProjects/untitled2/tests.py", line 21, in write_csv
    writer.writerow((data['title'],
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str 



import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


def request(url):
    """Get HTML code of any page"""
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_pagination(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    all_page = soup.find_all('a', class_='pagination-page')
    last_page = all_page[-1].get('href').split('=')[1].split('&')[0]

    return int(last_page)

def write_csv(data):
    with open('avito_estate.csv', 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow((data['title'],
                         data['href'],
                         data['price'],
                         data['category']))

def get_all_items(html):
    """Get all need items if html, argument is def request"""
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    all_items_soup = soup.find('div', class_='catalog-list').find_all('div', class_='item_table')
    all_items = []

    for item in all_items_soup:
        try:
            title = item.find('a', class_='item-description-title-link').get('title')
        except:
            title = ''
        try:
            href = 'https://www.avito.ru' + item.find('a', class_='item-description-title-link').get('href')
        except:
            href = ''
        try:
            price = item.find('div', class_='about').text.strip()
        except:
            price = ''
        try:
            category = item.find('div', class_='data').find('p').text.strip()
        except:
            category = ''
        data = {'title': title,
                'price': price,
                'href': href,
                'category': category}
        all_items.append(data)
    return all_items



#url с пагинацией
#https://www.avito.ru/kaliningrad/nedvizhimost?p=1&user=1

url = 'https://www.avito.ru/kaliningrad/nedvizhimost?p=1&user=1'
base_url = 'https://www.avito.ru/kaliningrad/nedvizhimost'
page_url = '?p='
last_url = '&user=1'

total_pages = get_pagination(request(url))

for i in range(1, total_pages):
    url_gen = base_url + page_url + str(i) + last_url
    html = request(url_gen)
    write_csv(get_all_items(html))
```

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что в функцию `write_csv` передан не словарь, а список. Попробуйте просто записать `writer.writerow(data)`.

Comment: Получилось! Сначала получил ошибку UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xb2' in position 21: character maps to <undefined>, если добавить кодировку utf-8: with open('avito_estate.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f, то все работает!! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Рабочий код

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


def request(url):
    """Get HTML code of any page"""
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_pagination(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    all_page = soup.find_all('a', class_='pagination-page')
    last_page = all_page[-1].get('href').split('=')[1].split('&')[0]

    return int(last_page)

def get_all_items(html):
    """Get all need items if html, argument is def request"""
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    all_items_soup = soup.find('div', class_='catalog-list').find_all('div', class_='item_table')

    for item in all_items_soup:
        try:
            title = item.find('a', class_='item-description-title-link').get('title')
        except:
            title = ''
        try:
            href = 'https://www.avito.ru' + item.find('a', class_='item-description-title-link').get('href')
        except:
            href = ''
        try:
            price = item.find('div', class_='about').text.strip()
        except:
            price = ''
        try:
            category = item.find('div', class_='data').find('p').text.strip()
        except:
            category = ''
        data = {'title': title,
                'price': price,
                'href': href,
                'category': category}
        with open('avito_estate.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow((data['title'],
                             data['href'],
                             data['price'],
                             data['category']))


#url с пагинацией
#https://www.avito.ru/kaliningrad/nedvizhimost?p=1&user=1

url = 'https://www.avito.ru/kaliningrad/nedvizhimost?p=1&user=1'
base_url = 'https://www.avito.ru/kaliningrad/nedvizhimost'
page_url = '?p='
last_url = '&user=1'

total_pages = get_pagination(request(url))

for i in range(1, 4):
    url_gen = base_url + page_url + str(i) + last_url
    html = request(url_gen)
    get_all_items(html)
```